# how to Get last Transaction For Ticket based on time stamp in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

[image: Based on the below Table on Bigquery "Type: is an actions applied on ticket, timestamp:was when Action Applied]

Sample data used:

```sql
with sample_data as (
select struct(111 as ticket_id, ['Open','ReOpen','Modified','Cancelled'] as type, [timestamp('2022-7-14 03:39:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 03:40:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 03:50:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 04:39:00')] as time_stamp) as ticket,
union all select struct(122 as ticket_id, ['Open','ReOpen','Modified'] as type, [timestamp('2022-7-14 07:39:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 07:40:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 07:50:00')] as time_stamp) as ticket
)
```

Expected output:

[image: i need to use Bigquery Code to export the last transaction Applied on the Tickets like this]

Comment: can you please share the schema of this table? it will help understand the data type of columns `Type` & `Time stamp`.

Comment: Type is a type of  Actions Applied to a Ticket &
Timestamp this was when Action Applied to The tickets

Comment: Is your schema like `struct<ticketID,array(type),array(timestamp)>`? Or is it something like `integer(ticketId),string(type),timestamp(timestamp)`?

Comment: yes struct<ticketID,array(type),array(timestamp)

Comment: thanks but last value work with using " ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try query below:

```sql
with sample_data as (
select struct(111 as ticket_id, ['Open','ReOpen','Modified','Cancelled'] as type, [timestamp('2022-7-14 03:39:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 03:40:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 03:50:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 04:39:00')] as time_stamp) as ticket,
union all select struct(122 as ticket_id, ['Open','ReOpen','Modified'] as type, [timestamp('2022-7-14 07:39:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 07:40:00'),timestamp('2022-7-14 07:50:00')] as time_stamp) as ticket
),


converted_timestamp as (
select 
  ticket.ticket_id,
  ticket.type,
  array(
    select 
      format_timestamp("%m/%d/%y %H:%M",stamp) 
    from unnest(ticket.time_stamp) as stamp
    order by stamp) as formated
from sample_data
),
---------
-- disregard query above as it just generates the sample data
---------
processed_data as (
select 
  ticket_id,
  last_value(t) over (partition by ticket_id order by f) as latest_type,
  max(f) over (partition by ticket_id) as latest_time
from converted_timestamp, 
unnest(formated) as f,
unnest(type) as t
)

select distinct ticket_id, latest_type,latest_time from processed_data
```

Output:

[image]